# Replacing string or object in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, rename

I'm setting up a by-region dataframe and have my data by country. I'm trying to put the various countries in a bucket that will fill in the region automatically in another column.

An issue I'm having is renaming (or replacing) values

Here's an example of values I'm trying to replace

1. Country (Given; Need to replace)

   - Germany Customs
   - Cote d'Ivoire
2. Preferred Value

   - Germany
   - Cote dIvoire

---

I'm running Spyder (latest version) and am utilizing Pandas for the operation

I first used the below function but was unsuccessful

```
DFColumn['Country'].replace("Cote d'Ivoire", 'Cote dIvoire')
```

Following this, I tried to convert the object dtype over to a string value. Still no dice

```py
DFColumn['Country'].astype(str)

DFColumn['Country'].str.replace("Cote d'Ivoire", 'Cote dIvoire')
```

Any thoughts or other methods I might try?

Comment: `DFColumn['Country'].replace("Cote d'Ivoire", 'Cote dIvoire')` should work but you need to assign it to the column: `DFColumn['Country'] = DFColumn['Country'].replace("Cote d'Ivoire", 'Cote dIvoire')`

Answer (score 0):

you can use dictionary with replace for multiple values

```
nametoreplace= {
              "Cote d'Ivoire":"Cote dIvoire",
              "Germany Customs": "Germany"
               }

DFColumn['Country']=DFColumn['Country'].replace(nametoreplace)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for mass replacement for a single column using pandas

```
df.Country = df.Country.replace({"Cote d'Ivoire": "Cote dIvoire","Germany Customs": "Germany"})
```